# external link to jqm-calendar page endless loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, calendar

I have a link to a jqm-calendar page on my home page.  The code below is placed in under  so the calendar will load each time a user visits the page.  When I click the jqm-calendar page link from my home page, I get this endless loading icon and the user isn't directed to jqm-calendar page.

```
    $("#games").live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
       $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
          events : [ 
          { "summary" : "Tryouts", "begin" : new Date("2014-09-07 00:00:00"), "end" : new Date("2014-09-07 00:00:00") }, 
          { "summary" : "Test event", "begin" : new Date(), "end" : new Date() }, 
          { "summary" : "Test event", "begin" : new Date(), "end" : new Date() } ],
          months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
          days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
          startOfWeek : 0
       });
    })
```

Comment: Are you using recent version of jQuery? `.live` is removed in 1.9

Comment: I am using version 1.8.2